# Select all in TextBox by clicking a button

Tags: c#, wpf, select, textbox, selection

I would like to highlight all content of a `TextBox` by a press of a button, but it doesn't work.

```
private void selectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

I tried this as well:

```
myTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
myTextBox.SelectionLength = myTextBox.Text.Length;
```

Not working. The properties seem to change, but the highlight is not present on the UI. If I select the text manually, the highlight works correctly.

What should I do?

Comment: In addition to what @neoistheone wrote this may be of interest...http://stackoverflow.com/a/2845657/2145211

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this, and you'll see the UI refresh:

```
myTextBox.Focus();
```